# Select on 3D-table along diagonal

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following data set on the form `(x, y, z)`

```
data = {
   {1, 1.1, 3},
   {2, 3, 5},
   {2.5, 4, 5},
   {4, 5, 6},
   {4.1, 4, 6},
   {100, 100, 6}};
```

I would like the data along the diagonal `x = y ± δ`, where `δ = 0.1` (as an example). I tried using this `Select`-statement,

```
ε = 0.1;
Select[data, -ε + #[[1]] < #[[2]] < +ε + #[[1]] &]
```

but that merely outputs `{{100, 100, 6}}`, which I don't seem to understand. Is `Select` the best method for extracting/filtering data like this and is it even possible?

Comment: Use `<=` and `>=` , since none of your data points actually meet your criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the reason for it not working is because you're using `Less` where you should be using `LessEqual` (if you expect to see more points).

```
In[1]:= Select[data, -ε + #[[1]] <= #[[2]] <= +ε + #[[1]] &]
Out[1]= {{1, 1.1, 3}, {4.1, 4, 6}, {100, 100, 6}}
```

That being said, I prefer using `Cases` and pattern matching for picking out elements from a list when I have to destructure the points to see if the match my criteria, since it allows you to be more explicit about what the various sub-parts mean. Also, use `Abs`!

```
In[2]:= Cases[data, {x_, y_, _} /; Abs[x - y] <= ε]
Out[2]= {{1, 1.1, 3}, {4.1, 4, 6}, {100, 100, 6}}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `Cases`, it looks more explicit than `Select` (it quickly becomes cumbersome I think)

Comment: @Billy, it's not about explicitness *per se*; altho almost anything expressed in one can be expressed in terms of the other, there are situations where using `Select[]` to pick elements of a list results in something tidier, and there are situation where `Cases[]` looks better than `Select[]`. Both have their place.